# Конвертация char в Virtual-Key Code для unicode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Необходимо передать `WM_KEYDOWN` через `SendMessage`, имея unicode `char` независимо от выбранной пользователем раскладки клавиатуры в конкретное окно.

```
IntPtr hwnd = ...;
char ch = 'я';
int keyCode = ch.???;    

NativeMethods.SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, keyCode, ...);
```

Как сконвертировать char в [Virtual Key Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx)?
`VkKeyScan` не подходит, т.к. он зависит от выбранной пользователем раскладки клавиатуры.

Comment: Откуда есть уверенность, что по символу можно однозначным образом получить keycode?

Comment: @yolosora да ладно однозначным, для большинства символов таких кодов и вовсе нет!

Comment: @yolosora такой уверенности нет, потому я и задал вопрос

Comment: @maxswitcher использовать обновлённую функцию [VkKeyScanEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646332(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: @John туда нужно передать HKL, а для этого нужно знать, к какому языку принадлежит символ.

Comment: @maxswitcher тогда мы приходим к простому выводу: никак. От языка зависит раскладка и нельзя иногда точно сказать к какой клавише относит тот или иной символ. Например, символ [À](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%80) во [французской](https://klaviatura.online.ua/fr/) и в [итальянской](https://klaviatura.online.ua/it/) раскладках находятся на разных клавишах. Так что придумывайте, что-нибудь с языком или делайте собственную таблицу char<->VkKey.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Keys ConvertCharToVirtualKey(char ch) {
    short vkey = VkKeyScan(ch);
    Keys retval = (Keys)(vkey & 0xff);
    int modifiers = vkey >> 8;
    if ((modifiers & 1) != 0) retval |= Keys.Shift;
    if ((modifiers & 2) != 0) retval |= Keys.Control;
    if ((modifiers & 4) != 0) retval |= Keys.Alt;
    return retval;
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);
```

Comment: Я же написал, что `VkKeyScan` не подходит.